# Bash - Reading from file descriptor simultaneously

Tags: bash, file-descriptor

I am working with Linux file descriptor at the moment to communicate with an external device via serial port, and I wonder if it is possible for me to duplicate the result returned the device.

In details, I used file descriptor number 5 to read and write to the serial port /dev/ttyACM0 in a raspbian device.

```
exec 5<>"/dev/ttyACM0"
```

In the background, I ran a function to continuously read from the port whenever a response was present to decide the next step.

```
function __processing__(){
   local line
   while read line<&5; do 
      ... some processing ...
      ... echo $line > "log.txt"
   done
}
```

And it has been working alright if I just sent single command to the serial port and let the background function to process the response. The issue appeared when I start working with other software to transfer data using XMODEM protocol, in the foreground.

```
sx -vv -k "./firmware_update.bin" >&5 <&5
```

The process kept timing out on ACK, despite the ACK responses recorded in the log file. So I suspected that it was because of the background process that read from FD5, leaving `sx` nothing. I then tried to remove the background process and run only the `sx` command, and my suspicion was confirmed when it successfully sent all data packages.

But then I don't have any recorded response from the serial port to actually know what to do next.

So my question is: Is there a way to rewrite the background function so that it can still read the response, without interfering with `sx`? I know that we can duplicate data from stdout using `tee` command, can I achieve something similar with FD5 instead?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Could it be a buffering issue?

Comment: Nod given for exceptionally well written question (somewhat rare these days...)

Comment: (1) Do you have Xmodem communications working on the rasbain device? (2) you are sending 1K packets, but is the device configured the same? (3) `>&5 <&5` redirecting to fd5 while trying to read from the same fd5 won't work. @pjh answer gives options to consider. If you don't have Xmodem working on the device, your other option is to `uuencode` the binary data and `uudecode` on the device. Other than copying or moving or using a 3rd party protocol like Xmodem, bash `read` isn't meant to read/write binary. Interesting issue. I use `ttyACM0` for microcontroller comm, but nothing like this.

Comment: Hi @DavidC.Rankin, thank you for your kind words. To answer some of your questions:
(1) Yes, I got Xmodem communications working on my Raspbian device using the above `sx` code.
(2) Xmodem-1k is actually required by the chip manufacturer. And you are right, I guess this is sort of related to embedded-system communications.
(3) I sort of imagine it could be something like this: We write to `/dev/ttyACM0` aka `FD5`. -> The chip is polling on this `FD5`, consuming what we write, which make it empty again. -> Then the chip write a response to `FD5`, we read from it, leaving it empty again.

Comment: I could be completely wrong about (3) though, but the code has been working fine. I actually take the idea from this answer on XMODEM: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553514/501482

Comment: How your device behaves will have a lot to do with whether it will work or not. If what you write of fd5 is read on the device, cleared and then what you need to read loaded into fd5 -- that could work. The general issue when a file-descriptor is associated with a regular file (that doesn't clear what is written before loading what needs to be read) is you end up trying to read what was just written and the single fd will basically dead-lock. Are you trying to load a firmware update on the rasbain device? Does it have an OS (like a PI) that could load it another way?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, The device I am trying to load the firmware on is not a Raspbian device, but rather connected to a Raspbian device via UART. It is a wireless Sierra chip, HL76xx, which uses a set of AT command for communication and data. Via `FD5`, I did manage to send these AT commands to the chip and read the response it sent back. The device does not have an OS, and the only way to send data to it is via XMODEM (from manufacturer documentation).

Comment: Okay, that is similar to uploading firmware to the old HP-Net-Direct devices that provided the network IP print capabilities to HP 4100+ type printers. That was more LFTP than the old Hayes AT command set, but similar. So you pass to the rasbain device and then out its UART to the Sierra chip (and then once the firmware file is there there are another set of AT type commands to load it?) So this looks like PC -> Rasbain and then Rasbain -> Sierra chip over Xmodem, right? And after the firmware is on the Sierra chip, how do you validate it is there ready to load?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242644/discussion-between-mduc1-6-and-david-c-rankin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sx -vv -k "./firmware_update.bin" >&5 < <(__processing__)
```

that uses Bash process substitution (see [ProcessSubstitution - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)) to cause `sx` to take its input from the output of the  `__processing__` function.  You'll also need to modify the function to copy its input (from FD5) to its standard output.  Something along the lines of:

```
function __processing__
{
    local line
    while IFS= read -r line<&5; do 
        # ... some processing ...
        printf '%s\n' "$line" > "log.txt"
        printf '%s\n' "$line"    # Copy input to standard output
   done
}
```

- That code is [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean.
- See function [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for an explanation of the changes that I made on the `while ...` line.
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I replaced `echo` with  `printf`.
- Note that, even with the changes that I made, the `__processing__` function won't work reliably if the data coming from FD5 is binary.  ASCII NUL characters will be lost (Bash strings can't contain them), and it depends on chunks of input being terminated by newline characters.  I don't know what kind of data you are dealing with in this case.  It may not be something that can be handled by Bash code.